# Is there any alternative to object-fit:contain?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to put 2 videos in my responsive page alternatively. One is portrait and one is landscape. `object-fit:contain` in my CSS looks fine in full desktop screen. But when I resize my page, huge padding from top and bottom appears when my landscape video is put in. What should I do to remove it and without editing my CSS manually for each video?

Also I have a video overlay(canvas) that should fit my video too, not the parent div.

Thank you! <3

HTML

```
<div id='media-player'>
    <canvas id="my-canvas"></canvas>
    <video id='media-video' preload="auto">
        <source src='media/snatch.mp4.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
        <source src='media/snatch.oggtheora.ogv' type='video/webm'>
    </video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#media-player
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
}
video
{
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    object-fit:contain;
}
#my-canvas
{
    position:absolute !important;
    z-index:100000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.0);
    height:inherit;
    width:inherit;
    background-color:#0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but oh well going to answer just in case someone runs into this problem

in order to maintain the aspect ratio on images or videos you can of course use

the

```
object-fit:contain;
```

but you will get object position this moves the image around gives is invisible margin so what you want to do is set it to 0 example below.

```
object-fit:contain;


object-position: 0% 0%;
```

By default it will be 50% 50% you just cant see it you also for better scaling just personal liking is to wrap the image or video in a container that way you can target the whole video or image and lets say you have a header underneath the video or some type of caption example below.

```
container video{ object-fit:contain; object-position: 0% 0%;}
```

this will target the container holding the media file. but again if you want to just target the image you can just copy the first example. I'll leave a link below for everyone to understand object-fit:
[enter link description here](https://css-tricks.com/on-object-fit-and-object-position/)

[object-fit info](https://css-tricks.com/on-object-fit-and-object-position/)